# Ask tips: For merging small figures into a big one with high resolution

Tags: software, visualization-software

my question is not related to material or modeling, but I guess many people in this community face it. I took a figure of a crystal structure by cropping the VESTA app on my laptop screen; band and DOS figures were plotted and exported from Gnuplot. I would like to combine them into one with high resolution for thesis and publication. I tried Microsoft PowerPoint to group and then export to a png file. The problem is that the obtained figure does not have a high resolution and its size does not fit the requirements of the journal. Can you suggest some tips or softwares that may export not only crystal structure but also merge figures?

Comment: Export everything as an SVG and merge them in inkscape for perfect quality. For very good quality, just export with a high resolution PNG (1600x1600) is usually fine for me and combine everything in powerpoint, then re-export as a PNG.

Comment: SVG or not, vector graphics are your friend.

Comment: Unfortunately, VESTA does not create usable vector graphics in my experience.

Comment: @HaydenS, VESTA can export SVG images: Please choose File --> Export Vector Image. In File type, you can choose SVG file

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out?  Was the comment by @jheindel helpful? jheindel can you write a full answer?